# How to split a live logging file in Python?

Tags: python, logging, archive, live

I'm relatively new to Python, so apologies in advance if this is a stupid question, but I've searched for about 2 hours and can't find an answer.

I have a short python script that is appending csv data to a file (data.csv) about every second. The format of the data is:

epoch_time,int1,int2,int3...intn

and the file has a single line header.

data.csv is being read by live charting software and it is expanding at about 20mb per day.

Is there a way or set of routines that will strip the file of data (and archive it into other files) that is older than say 12 hours, while still leaving the single line header and data.csv open to receiving data?

Thanks.

Ok, so I'm bad, because I haven't tried this, but I know how to read the data into a list and split it from there and write it back out, but I suspect that this will take longer than a second and I'll have random data points mixed in and it's now a live environment, so I'm not to comfortable playing around with it. I may have to strip it every hour, so that it doesn't take so long, but I'm still dealing with 40k+ records if I'm looking at 12 hours of data. Any assistance or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does the thing keep the file descriptor open all the time or opens only for writing? Does it re-create the file if missing? If only for writing and re-creates -> just periodically rename the existing file. If only for writing but doesn't re-create -> rename+make a stub (or copy existing stub) with old name.